# Change svg.js text in group with animation

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, svg.js

I have two functions. The first creates a group, draws a line,
Adds a line to the group, takes its coordinates and displays them under the line of text, the text is added to the group too. Second, animates the movement group.

```
  animate: function(x, y, draw) {
    this.group.animate(1000, '-', 0).move(x, y);
  },

  linePainting: function(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, textY, draw, color) {
    this.group = draw.group().x(x1).y(y1);
    this.line = draw.line(x2, y2, x3, y3).stroke({ width: 1, color: "#" + color });
    this.group.add(this.line);
    pos = this.group.x().toFixed(1);
    this.text = this.group.add(draw.text(pos.toString()).x(-10).y(textY));
  },
```

How i can The function linePainting is called only once, after 1 call the animate.

I have 2 question.

1. How do I change the text in a group?
2. is it possible to animate the text? For example, if there were 100, the following number of 150, to within one second of the smoothly from 100 to 150.

I very much hope that the answer to the question Wout)

Answer (score 1):

First: You put something in `this.text` but thats not the text as you might think but the group because `add()` returns `this` and not the added element.

Use `put()` instead to get the `text` back.

Now you can simply call `this.text.text('new Text')` to change the text.

Second: <s>There is nothing like text morphing (how would one implement that?). But you can easily change the text to another number with each animation step.</s>

Take a look at [svg.textmorph.js](https://github.com/Fuzzyma/svg.textmorph.js) which makes text animatable. You need an svg-font for that.